# Ayuda con vps ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

Hola amigo acabo de instalar  **xorg lxde** el escritorio en un *vps* con **Ubuntu 14.04** me conecto con *tightvncserver* y todo bien el problema esta que e instalado *hitleap* descargando este paquete `HitLeap Viewer.tar.xz` lo instalo con este comando  `tar xpvf "/root/HitLeap Viewer.tar.xz"`.

A la hora de arrancar *hitleap* bien pero luego de 1 o 2 minutos se cierra solo y no entiendo por que razón o como dejarlo funcionando sin que se cierre .

Estas son las especificaciones del *vps*:

- Operating System -> Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
- IPv6 Address     -> 1
- Disk Space       -> 40 GB
- Bandwidth        -> 1000 GB
- Memory           -> 1 GB
- VSwap            -> 256 MB

Espero su ayuda o alguna idea.

Comment: No parece versar sobre programación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que te esta ocurriendo es un error de inestabilidad:

http://www.webhostwhat.com/guide-to-hitleap-on-ubuntu-linux-viewer-install-easy-instructions/

http://www.webhostwhat.com/linux-vps-guide-to-remote-ubuntu-desktop-vnc-easy-instructions/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nuñes gracias por la información problema resuelto